# Docker desktop cannot start, unable to calculate image disk size

Tags: docker

I am having issues trying to open Docker on Windows 11 after installing. I followed the instructions on the Docker website, and have a working WSL 2 installation. When I try to open Docker Desktop, the application first shows a red banner that says "Unable to calculate image disk size" and then freezes. Docker Desktop does not have a storage size listed in the app list.

During the installation process, I do not see se WSL 2 instead of Hyper-V option on the Configuration page. When I run the command ".\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe check", I get the following error message (edited for brevity):

```
failed to ping VM diagnosticsd with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can provide the full message if need be but Stack Overflow keeps marking this post as spam. I have looked online for potential solutions but none have worked. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, modifying $PATH, pruning Docker, running Docker outside of Docker Desktop.